# Image is not shown in email MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email

I have a strange problem.
I need to send an e-mail from an MVC site. I have an `html` template for the email, which looks like this(the image part):

```
...
<img class="auto-style4" src="{PictureSrc}" /><br />
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{pictureBase64}"> 
....
```

From the controller I'm replacing the parameters like this:

```
  case "PictureSrc":
         string imagePath = "";
         imagePath = "~/Images/email-logo.png";
          //string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(HttpContext.Server.MapPath(imagePath)));

         //content = content.Replace("{pictureBase64}", base64);
         content = content.Replace("{" + property + "}", HttpContext.Server.MapPath(imagePath));
                    break;
```

1.First I have tried to add the path for the image. This way works on my local machine, but not on the server where the live site is.

2. I've tried to add the URL for the image. WhenI have pasted the URL in to the browser, the image was shown, but in the sent email the image was not shown, not in my local  machine, not on the server.
   The interesting thing is that I'm sending these mails to outlook accounts. There the images are not shown, but if I send the mail to my yahoo account there the image is shown.
3. I've tried to convert image to base 64, as you can see on the `code` and replacing this way the `image src`. This way again the image was not shown, not on my local  machine, not on the server side if I send the mail to outlook accounts. If I send the mail to a yahoo account, the mail is shown.

Can you please advise what can I try in order to resolve this problem?

Comment: " There the images are not shown, but if I send the mail to my yahoo account there the image is shown." To me this indicates it's unlikely to be an issue with your code. More likely it's a setting in Outlook which prohibits downloading images and other external resources into the email by default. You should be able to control this setting somewhere in Outlook, where exactly you do this may depend on the version you're using, but it should be possible to google about it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue with Outlook a few months ago. While researching, I learned that Outlook tends to strip emails of embedded images. I resolved it by using the CID technique. This technique consists of attaching the image to the email and referencing it in the email template with the image's CID.

First, you would need to get your image's CID. There are plenty of CID converters online to do this. Then, you just need to use the CID in the `img src` attribute of your template: `<img src="cid:" + yourCID + "/>"`.

Note: this WILL increase the size of your email due to the image being attached.